# BQ command line tool -- how to check if a BigQuery dataset exists before creating it?

Tags: google-bigquery

Using the BigQuery command-line tool, how can I check if a dataset exists before creating it?

```
bq mk dataset
```

reports an error if you try to call it on an already existing dataset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A shorter solution:

```
bq show $dataset || bq mk $dataset
```

Answer (score 5):

List all the datasets in the project, and use grep -w to check if the dataset you want is already there. To issue a "bq mk" only if the dataset doesn't already exist:

```
#!/bin/bash
bq_safe_mk() {
    dataset=$1
    exists=$(bq ls -d | grep -w $dataset)
    if [ -n "$exists" ]; then
       echo "Not creating $dataset since it already exists"
    else
       echo "Creating $dataset"
       bq mk $dataset
    fi
}

# this is how you call the function
bq_safe_mk someowenwoiertw
```

Comment: If you have a projects with > 50 datasets, bq ls is limited to 50, so you might need to add -n 1000 as in ```bq ls -n 1000 -d | ...```

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to @Lak's answer to work in safe bash env

```
#!/bin/bash
# safer bash: check for errors and unset variables
set -Eeuo pipefail

bq_safe_mk() {
    dataset=$1
    exists=$(bq ls -d | { grep -w $dataset || :; })
    if [ -n "$exists" ]; then
       echo "Not creating $dataset since it already exists"
    else
       echo "Creating $dataset"
       bq mk $dataset
    fi
}

bq_safe_mk adatasetname
```